# TheIntern Dojo example exits with timeout error

Tags: javascript, dojo, intern

The Example of Dojo tests run under Intern (https://github.com/theintern/intern-examples/tree/master/dojo-example) does not actually test anything, fails on connect to the Sauce network:

```
$ npm test
> dojo-intern-example@0.1.0 test /home/bogdanbiv/WebstormProjects/intern-examples/dojo-example
> intern-runner config=tests/intern
Listening on 0.0.0.0:9001
Starting tunnel...
Using no proxy for connecting to Sauce Labs REST API.
**********************************************************
A newer version of Sauce Connect (build 1283) is available!
Download it here:
https://saucelabs.com/downloads/sc-4.3-linux.tar.gz
**********************************************************
Started scproxy on port 49172.
Starting secure remote tunnel VM...
Secure remote tunnel VM provisioned.
Tunnel ID: 2f904e21cf1e4c3e83f63a4b3089127c
Secure remote tunnel VM is now: booting
Secure remote tunnel VM is now: running
Remote tunnel host is: maki76020.miso.saucelabs.com
Using no proxy for connecting to tunnel VM.
Establishing secure TLS connection to tunnel...
Cleaning up.
Finished! Deleting tunnel.
Error: failed to connect to tunnel VM.
Error: failed to connect to tunnel VM.
  at reject  <node_modules/intern/node_modules/digdug/SauceLabsTunnel.js:353:17>
  at readStartupMessage  <node_modules/intern/node_modules/digdug/SauceLabsTunnel.js:381:12>
  at <node_modules/intern/node_modules/digdug/SauceLabsTunnel.js:434:12>
  at Array.some  <native>
  at Socket.<anonymous>  <node_modules/intern/node_modules/digdug/SauceLabsTunnel.js:428:21>
  at Socket.EventEmitter.emit  <events.js:117:20>
  at Socket.<anonymous>  <_stream_readable.js:746:14>
  at Socket.EventEmitter.emit  <events.js:92:17>
  at emitReadable_  <_stream_readable.js:408:10>
  at emitReadable  <_stream_readable.js:404:5>
npm ERR! weird error 1
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Ok it does complain about having an old Sauce Connect binary, but even after downloading and inserting the path of the newest SC (4.3). I also updated .bin/intern-runner to contain `js` as a running environment as opposed to the old `node` command. User and password are the ones from the repository (left them unchanged). I followed the documentation and did uncomment the tunnel in the intern config file.

**UPDATE**: This problem still occurs. I find it wierd that a proxy is started `Started scproxy on port 54687.`, but, further down, `Using no proxy for connecting to tunnel VM.`. Aren't these lines supposed to match? 
It could be that this mismatch has nothing to do with the original problem? The new Sauce Connect binary is still ignored.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: Actually this solution affects only client, local - `intern-client config=tests/intern`. As a result this solution solves a different problem than the one originally posted. /**UPDATE**

The problem was that although I executed `bower install` as documented, the bower components installed in a folder set by the bowerrc global configuration. This was quite different from what the Dojo TodoMVC example required for its components.

Also submitted an issue at https://github.com/theintern/intern-examples/issues/10 and a pull request.